# Change a domain IP in iOS using a mobileconfig

Tags: ios, mobile-config

Earlier I was searching on google for a way to change a domain iP on my device (iOS) then I found an article saying that it is possible using mobileconfig, they left an example but to be truthful, I dont know how to edit it. I want to change localhost.apple.com DNS to 127.0.0.1, Can someone help me change this example to what I want!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>PayloadContent</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string>DoT - example.com</string>
            <key>PayloadDescription</key>
            <string>Configures device to use example.com Encrypted DoT</string>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>DoT - example.com</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.dnsSettings.managed.AFCA1444-5AEB-44CD-B23D-5D1B3ADCD1EE</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.dnsSettings.managed</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>A6F9CB2D-F00E-4C3A-90EB-E19E5B872C4F</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>DNSSettings</key>
            <dict>
                <key>DNSProtocol</key>
                <string>TLS</string>
                <key>ServerAddresses</key>
                <array>
                    <string>xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::xx11</string>
                    <string>x.x.1.1</string>
                </array>
                <key>ServerName</key>
                <string>ns.example.com</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>

</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Your question is off topic because it isn't about programming, but the payload doesn't change the mapping of ip to a host name, it changes the device DNS server - the address of the server that resolves names to IP addresses. You can do that in the network settings of your device. You would need to run your own dns server that had the name resolution you wanted.

Comment: Can you tell me how to?